Chassidic and Traditional Clothing
Strange question. As a lay leader under Aleph, I am usually pretty good at finding resources. For example, I had a Soldier ask me how to find a more affordable fedora and kapota because they wanted to start wearing that on Shabbos and Yomim Tovim. Now, I have a new one that I am running into walls. Apparently, one of the airmen at the local airbase has been heavily influenced by the Breslev and is working on joining a Breslev community when he retires in two years (this was relayed to me by a Christian Chaplain--so I have yet to talk to him) and it brought up another interesting point-What are the best options for finding hassidic, Litvishe, and other traditional garb. In this case, he is looking for a Yerushalmi Bekitcha. I am striking out with the exception of eBay.
For example, I know that many Litvishe and Chabad (as well as others) go with Borsalino for their fedoras. From this site, I was actually find to find Sterkowski for the first Soldier I listed (I also bought a couple of flat caps from them).
So, can everybody post links of where they have been able to find proper, and appropriate traditional clothing? Also--if anyone knows where to get solid copies of the Mishnah Berurah with the English translation in a linear fashion--that would also be wonderful as that has been a hard one!
It is strange that this keeps coming up, but as a lay leader I like to make sure that I am supporting everyone in their journey--even if it is outside of my community/knowledge base. I also know of a lot of great places to get Tallitot (Ben's is my favorite), but I will take that and normal judaica as well. I have between 5-10 more years of uniformed service and I look forward to help Jews who come to more observance (as I did) along the way.
Toda Raba!

Hey Boaz, welcome to Mi Yodeya. You might try splitting your questions into two separate posts, so that each one can get its own attention. With regards to the Bekitcha, I would look into contacting stores in Boro Park that specialize in chassidic garb, they may not have an online presence.

I am only aware of one printed translation of Mishna Brura, from Ohr Olam, see here on this site for details. But it is not linear (if by that mean having the English below each word of the Hebrew)

It all depends on what he wants exactly. Hassidic Royal Clothing is one option. They have a store and a website. I'm sure if you can get a tailor to take measurements then they can help you.
Side note. It would really be important too that this person is stable and established in his observance before changing lots of details about his life. Often when people make quick and radical changes in coming closer to Torah Judaism they don't hold onto it for very long. They realize that other Orthodox Jews are flawed humans and become disillusioned or something else happens to damper their baal teshuva excitement.
There is a Rashi that explains that the altar has a ramp rather than stairs so to not expose the nakedness of the priest walking up. In a deeper sense when a person is approaching holiness such as a baal teshuva it's important to take a slow and steady path like a ramp to be successful. I'm not saying that things like clothing can never be adopted but only after some time when the person is ready.
All the best!

I agree fully. I just want to have the resources since it has happened previously. I still have not met the one that I was asked about Breslov attire. I really will not try to lead him in any direction, but just want to provide him with what he needs.
